# Sending attachment with MailKit in PowerShell doesn't attach

Tags: powershell, mailkit

I have a simple script in PowerShell to simply SMTP a PDF attachment. No subject, and no body. The results show the attachment but the email is always received without it. Am I missing something?

```
$SMTP = [MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient]::new()
$Message = [MimeKit.MimeMessage]::new()
$Builder = [MimeKit.BodyBuilder]::new()

$Message.From.Add("myname@mydomain.com")
$Message.To.Add("yourname@yourdomain.com")
$Builder.Attachments.Add("C:\Users\myname\Path\MyPDF.pdf")

$SMTP.Connect('smtp.xxxx.com', 465, 'SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect')
$SMTP.Authenticate($MAILCREDENTIALS)

$SMTP.Send($Message)
$SMTP.Disconnect($true)
$SMTP.Dispose()
```

Output after sending:

```
ContentDuration         : 
ContentMd5              :
ContentTransferEncoding : Base64
FileName                : MyPDF.pdf
Content                 : MimeKit.MimeContent
ContentObject           : MimeKit.MimeContent
Headers                 : {Content-Type: application/pdf; name="MyPDF.pdf", Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyPDF.pdf", Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64}  
ContentDisposition      : Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyPDF.pdf"
ContentType             : Content-Type: application/pdf; name="MyPDF.pdf"
ContentBase             :
ContentLocation         :
ContentId               :
IsAttachment            : True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to look at this project on Github: https://github.com/EvotecIT/Mailozaurr 
It is built on top of MimeKit and MailKit.

Regarding your code, try adding this just after "$Builder.Attachments.Add....".

```
$Message.Body = $Builder.ToMessageBody()
```

Comment: I had tried that line previously but it was *before* and not *after* the "$Builder.Attachments.Add...." . Thanks a bunch for the sharp eye and catching that!!